# How to pass a list of string values to a picklist in a flow

Tags: visual-workflow, picklist, list, string, collection

I currently pass a list of strings from my apex class to a flow. The list of strings `{!cancellationReasonsList}` I pass to a choice recource. The choice recource I pass to a picklist. Instead of ending up with a picklist I get 1 value with the whole list of strings. What am I mising?

I found this answer but dont see what is different: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000AaLOIA0

Flow
Choice resource
[image]

Picklist
[image]

Value screen picklist
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now, there isn't a way to pass a list of string values and display as dynamic choices in the flow's picklist component.

You can check for some alternatives in a similar question asked. ([Screen Flow Picklist from Lightning Component](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/295524/screen-flow-picklist-from-lightning-component/295532#295532)).

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this today using the [Quick Choice extension](https://unofficialsf.com/quick-choice-improved-picklists-and-radio-buttons-for-flow/)

Choice resources can be confusing. Each one represents literally a single choice.In the page that you link to, a single value is being assigned to a single choice resource. In theory you could define 20 choice resources and assign a different choice to each one, but just use Quick Choice instead until we add this properly to the built-in picklist support.